# Drupal 8 url after installation using drush site-install

Tags: drush

I used Composer to download and install Drupal 8.8.1 on Linux and used drush site:install command for setup.

Only the following lines/messages were shown after I entered drush site:install command.

```
You are about to DROP all tables in your 'drupal8' database. Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:

>yes

[notice]Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while.
[success] Installation complete. User name and password displayed.
```

I don't know my site URL. How do I find my site URL? Is there a default site URL?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) You have to configure any URL you want on your Linux yourself. Have Apache installed, have a conf for your site enabled naming an URL and to which folder it should point to, and maybe also have the /etc/hosts file adjusted to map your URL to 127.0.0.1. But actually this doesn't have much to do with Drupal at all. But with local web development in general instead.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on getting this far. You got Drupal and Drush downloaded and were able to configure the database. Those can both be challenging things to do.

Based on your description it seems like do not have a webserver. Drupal.org has [some documentation on setting up a webserver](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/web-server) and there are a few solutions to that, like setting up apache or nginx.

Since you mentioned you have drush available one of the easiest solutions is to use drush's `runserver` command. It is [documented here](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/core/runserver/)

From the project root run the command:

```
drush runserver
```

The output of that command will tell you the URL to load into your browser. By default the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8888` which it will tell you `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8888`.

Here's [a more detailed article from Lullabot on runserver](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/the-simplest-path-to-a-drupal-local-environment).

Comment: Thanks, Greggles. I have Apache 2.4.4 installed in my test environment. In any case, I did try 'drush rs' still didn't see the homepage of my site. I am tired, will look into this issue tomorrow.